# Root file not being read correctly from plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to access a root file that I have created from a plugin I've made, the path seems to be correct but instead, I'm getting the error message.

```php
$file = fopen("~/home/app_name/.token", "r") or die("Unable to open job ads file!");
$access_token_new = fgets($file,filesize("~/home/app_name/.token"));
```

When I run the file via CLI I'm getting a `401 Unauthorised` access due to the `fopen` failing, any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are the rights on the file to read. And what are the rights of the script executing the reading...?

Comment: The rights to read the file should be fine as I'm able to write to it from a file at the same level, I'm not sure on the second one

Comment: And in your PHP code if you test if the file exists...? What does it give...?

Comment: HI Juan, weirdly I've managed to fix the issue by removing the tilde symbol, it was my understanding that this set the path to the root but apparently WordPress don't give an f lol

Comment: I was just going to ask you if the tilde wasn't a problem. This is why I advised you to test the existence of the file with this path and this tilde

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247841/discussion-between-juan-and-sam-st-aubyn).